# Key/Value Pairs in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matlab, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I created by merging multiple MATLAB `.mat` files and then loading the merged list of dictionaries to pandas.

```
    KEY_COLUMN                                  VALUE_COLUMN
0   [[[KEY1]], [[KEY2]], [[KEY3]], [[KEY4]]]    [[VALUE], [VALUE], [VALUE], [VALUE]]
1   [[[KEY2]], [[KEY3]], [[KEY1]], [[KEY4]]]    [[VALUE], [VALUE], [VALUE], [VALUE]]
2   [[[KEY1]], [[KEY3]], [[KEY4]], [[KEY2]]]    [[VALUE], [VALUE], [VALUE], [VALUE]]
```

```
{'TYPE': {0: array([[array(['START'], dtype='<U5')],
         [array(['DIST'], dtype='<U6')],
         [array(['DISTFALSE'], dtype='<U7')],
         [array(['DISTTRUE'], dtype='<U7')],
         [array(['ENCFALSE'], dtype='<U11')],
         [array(['ENCTRUE'], dtype='<U12')]], dtype=object),
  1: array([[array(['DISTFALSE'], dtype='<U5')],
         [array(['START'], dtype='<U10')],
         [array(['DIST'], dtype='<U11')],
         [array(['DISTTRUE'], dtype='<U11')],
         [array(['ENCTRUE'], dtype='<U10')],
         [array(['ENCFALSE'], dtype='<U11')]], dtype=object)},
 'TIME': {0: array([[ 24413],
         [ 27481],
         [ 29382],
         [ 31923],
         [ 31249],
         [ 34690]]),
  1: array([[ 364582],
         [ 31234],
         [ 43123],
         [ 24444],
         [ 55551],
         [ 12355]])}}
```

now I would want to have the KEYS be columns and VALUES be rows of the dataframe like here:

```
    KEY1     KEY2     KEY3     KEY4
0   VALUE    VALUE    VALUE    VALUE
1   VALUE    VALUE    VALUE    VALUE
2   VALUE    VALUE    VALUE    VALUE
```

The issue is that the order of keys (and consecutively values) is not the same. It differs between the current rows.

How to achieve that?
Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some example of your dataframe and the desired result (with real names and not just key-value)

Comment: Please provide sample data by using `df.head(5).to_dict()` since you have nested values.

Comment: If loading the file gives you such a result, it is probably best to load the file in a different way, instead of trying to rescue this messy dataframe afterwards.

Comment: @HenryYik just added it

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following approach to solve this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TYPE': {0: np.array([[np.array(['START'], dtype='<U5')],[np.array(['DIST'], dtype='<U6')],[np.array(['DISTFALSE'], dtype='<U7')],[np.array(['DISTTRUE'], dtype='<U7')],[np.array(['ENCFALSE'], dtype='<U11')],[np.array(['ENCTRUE'], dtype='<U12')]], dtype=object),
  1: np.array([[np.array(['DISTFALSE'], dtype='<U5')],[np.array(['START'], dtype='<U10')],[np.array(['DIST'], dtype='<U11')],[np.array(['DISTTRUE'], dtype='<U11')],[np.array(['ENCTRUE'], dtype='<U10')],[np.array(['ENCFALSE'], dtype='<U11')]], dtype=object)},
 'TIME': {0: np.array([[ 24413],[ 27481],[ 29382],[ 31923],[ 31249],[ 34690]]),
  1: np.array([[ 364582],[ 31234],[ 43123],[ 24444],[ 55551],[ 12355]])}})

# Assuming a df as shown in the problem statement

#Initialize an empty dictionary to hold extracted keys and values
keyvals = {}
    
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    keyrow = df.iloc[i, 0].flatten()
    valrow = df.iloc[i, 1].flatten()
    for j,k in zip(keyrow, valrow):
        try:
            keyvals[j].append(k)
        except:
            keyvals[j] = []
            keyvals[j].append(k)
        finally:
            pass

finDf = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in keyvals.items()]))
```

finDf is finally in this form:

```
      DISTF  START   DIST  DISTTRUE  ENCTRUE  ENCFALSE  DISTFAL  DISTTRU
0  364582.0  24413  27481   24444.0    34690     31249  29382.0  31923.0
1       NaN  31234  43123       NaN    55551     12355      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: Well, i defined my own dictionary to create a similar dataframe as yours but now you have also added the type so this solution needs an update.

Comment: Thanks! Changed it a bit

Comment: Updated, pls check now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a new dataframe by mapping key value pairs inside a list comprehension and using `np.squeeze` to remove the single dimensions:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(*map(np.squeeze, v))) for v in df.to_numpy()])
```

Result:

```
# for sample data
    KEY1   KEY2   KEY3   KEY4
0  VALUE  VALUE  VALUE  VALUE
1  VALUE  VALUE  VALUE  VALUE
2  VALUE  VALUE  VALUE  VALUE

# for actual data
   START   DIST  DISTFAL  DISTTRU  ENCFALSE  ENCTRUE     DISTF  DISTTRUE
0  24413  27481  29382.0  31923.0     31249    34690       NaN       NaN
1  31234  43123      NaN      NaN     12355    55551  364582.0   24444.0
```

Comment: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: @thisguy The code is working fine for me as per the sample data you have provided...

Comment: Sorry, my bad :P